# how to properly add/subtract business days for NYSE trading/holidays

Tags: r, calendar

I am trying to extract price data from yahoo finance for -beforeDays to +afterDays days around the lockup expiration date (180 days from the ipo). The problem is when I check to to see the number of dates retrieved from yahoo finance, it varies. I need to have the same number of observations for each ticker. I am guessing that I have not set the calendar/holidays right.

The code is as follows. The variable tickerdata has the data from the request to yahoo.

```
cal  <- create.calendar("UnitedStates/NYSE", weekdays=c("saturday", "sunday"))
for(i in seq(1,numrows , 1)) {

    ticker=tickerdata[i,"Ticker"];
    IPO.dat <- as.Date(tickerdata[i,"Date"],format="%yyyy-%m-%d");
    from.dat<-bizdays::offset(IPO.dat, 180-beforeDays, cal);
    to.dat<-bizdays::offset(IPO.dat, 180+afterDays, cal);

   if (to.dat<TodayDate.dat) {
      possibleError <- tryCatch(
        { 
        histData<- getSymbols(ticker, src="yahoo", from = from.dat, to =     
                 to.dat,adjust=TRUE,auto.assign=FALSE);
        print(paste("num rows: ",nrow(histData),"for ticker:",ticker,sep="") )
        },
        error=function(cond) { 
             message(paste("Error for ticker:",ticker,sep=""));
        },
        warning=function(cond) {
        message(paste("Error for ticker:",ticker,sep=""));
      },
      finally={
      }
    ) # end of catch
}
```

}

Sample output looks like:
[1] "num rows: 57for ticker:DNKN"

[1] "num rows: 57for ticker:AMID"

[1] "num rows: 54for ticker:SAVE"

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the tickerdata dataframe? Would be helpful to reproduce and see whats going on. Also: Where is the function "create.calender" from or what does it do?

Comment: There are at least two posts on SO for constructing the number of weekdays from one date to another. These would be a good first step.

Comment: lmo - your reference is rather vague, can you provide a http link? or reference?

Comment: guscht -  The data resides in an excel file,  the code to read it is:   tickerdata <- read.xlsx(IPODataInputFile, 2, as.data.frame=TRUE) ; 
tickerdata$Ticker<-as.character(tickerdata$Ticker)                                                                                                                                                               I pulled two records from the dataset, so it looks like following (separate lines for each ticker):        Ticker Date
SAVE  5/26/2011                                                      
AMID 7/27/2011